# Increase a Counter using 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to increase a counter which is initially 0,
to 1000 using 2 threads. Here is my code

```
class CounterVar {
  private int val;

  CounterVar() {
    val = 0;
  }

  public void increment() {
    Object obj = new Object();
    synchronized(obj) {
      val++;
    }
  }

  public int getVal() {
    return val;
  }
}

public class Counter {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    CounterVar counter = new CounterVar();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(() - > {
      for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        counter.increment();
    });
    Thread t2 = new Thread(() - > {
      for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        counter.increment();
    });
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println(counter.getVal());
  }
}
```

I am not getting output as 1000 here, its always less. I have implemented synchronization and dont understand what is wrong here.
Also wanted to clarify if I am starving thread2 while thread1 is incrementing the counter.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your synchronized `obj` is not shared, it is just a local object, so it does not prevent mutual exclusion the critical section with `val++`. You need to synchronize with an object that each thread has access to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not synchronizing the threads correctly. To synchronize multiple threads, you have to use a common object as the synchronization mechanism, but you are creating a new object for each thread. Instead, try this:

```
class CounterVar {
  private int val;
  private final Object obj = new Object();

  public void increment() {
    synchronized(obj) {
      val++;
    }
  }
```

Or, simpler without the `obj`:

```
public synchronized void increment() {
  ...
}
```